# how to use popup in iframe that covers the whole page which contains the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, popup

I want to create an iframe of size 200X200. and i want to use a popup code in it. but i am facing a problem,

currently the pop up is showing when i click on the space 200x200 but i want the popup to be displayed when i click on the page which have the iframe. (not only the iframe area but the whole page)

whenever i place the iframe on a page i want the popup to be apear as it's the popup of the original page not the iframe only.

Any one have any idea how i can perform this action with html, javascript or jquery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autoresize javascript code

```
<script type="Text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
function resize_iframe()
{
    var height=window.innerWidth;//Firefox
    if (document.body.clientHeight)
    {
        height=document.body.clientHeight;//IE
    }
    //resize the iframe according to the size of the
    //window (all these should be on the same line)
    document.getElementById("cam").style.height=parseInt(height-
    document.getElementById("cam").offsetTop-8)+"px";
}

// this will resize the iframe every
// time you change the size of the window.
window.onresize=resize_iframe; 

//Instead of using this you can use: 
//  <BODY onresize="resize_iframe()">

</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="cam" width="100%" scrolling="yes" src="http://www.your_page.com" onload="resize_iframe()">
</iframe>
</body>
```

this will help for you

Answer (score 0):

Make the pop-up call when the user click in an element of the body, not only the frame.
If you provide your JavaScript & HTML code, I can help you more.